# Counting the number of occurrences of specific words in latex

Tags: calculations

I have defined `\GreenCircle`, `\AmberCircle` and `\RedCircle` to display a green or an amber or a red circle before the beginning of the paragraph depending on the content of the paragraph. Would it be possible to tally up the number of each of these circles at the end of the document while running latex? Something like:

```
Number of Green Circles:
Number of Amber Circles:
Number of Red Circles:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, define a counter for each circle type and use `\stepcounter{redcircle}` etc. in your `\RedCircle` command etc, at the end use `\theredcircle`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{redcircle}
\newcounter{greencircle}
\newcounter{ambercircle}


\newcommand{\RedCircle}{%
  \stepcounter{redcircle}%
  % Rest of the redcircle command
}

\newcommand{\GreenCircle}{%
  \stepcounter{greencircle}%
  % Rest of the greencircle command
}

\newcommand{\AmberCircle}{%
  \stepcounter{ambercircle}%
  % Rest of the amberircle command
}



\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\RedCircle
\blindtext[10]

\RedCircle
\blindtext[10]



\GreenCircle
\blindtext

\AmberCircle
\blindtext
\GreenCircle
\blindtext


\clearpage
Number of Green Circles: \thegreencircle

Number of Red Circles: \theredcircle

Number of Amber Circles: \theambercircle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I will update with a better version later on

Comment: Works like a charm.